# Laravel sending email with axios post

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

i am making an application with laravel, vue and axios. i am sending mail notification from my application without problem.

But.....

I am having a vue component that uploads images, write to database and then sends an email.
The upload step and the database step working fine. I can't send email (thirt step). I am getting and 500 Internal Server Error.

The mystery is that i can send email from other places in my application but not in tha specific component.

Comment: Please provide some code if you want help

Comment: In `storage/logs/laravel.log` should be written why 500 is triggered.